# Checking template parameter against enum value in std::is_same

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Consider the following:

```
enum color {
    r, g, b 
};

template <color T>
constexpr bool is_green = std::is_same<T, color::g>::value;
```

g++ fails to compile this, erroring with

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for `template<class, class> struct std::is_same`

It's clearly acceptable to declare a templated class using an enum parameter as

```
template <color foo>
class widget
```

however, so it seems that it there should be some way to check the value as well (for later use in a conditional; `static_if` would have been nice but that requires c++17).

Comment: fwiw `std::euqal_to` (not to be confused with `std::equal`) compares values, but you dont need it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::is_same` compares on *types*, not *values*. You can just use `==` to compare values. e.g.

```
template <color T>
constexpr bool is_green = T == color::g;
```

and

> It's clearly acceptable to declare a templated class using an enum parameter

Yes you can. But note that it's [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter), not [type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter).

Answer (score 1):

```
template <color T>
constexpr bool is_green = T == color::g;
```

I mean... yeah :)